# how to hide message printed by django server

Tags: django

I have a question now. I want to hide out the message by django server such as 'get  /index.html...', that is the response to client side. How can I do it?

Comment: I don't know the answer but, I'm really curious on why you would want to impose such behaviour ?

Comment: you want for development server that comes with django?

Comment: If you're talking about apache verbosity, have a look at http://www.webreference.com/programming/Apache-Logging/index.html

Comment: Thx. I have a django_socketio server that handles instant messages, I want to hide the messages because maybe it's more efficient and what's most important is that when I type cmd in it, I won't be interrupted by the messages. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hiding development server's messages is not supported directly by django, but you can do that by modifying django's code. Just open file:

`[PYTHON site-packages]/django/core/servers/basehttp.py`

in a text editor and comment the line (line 200 in django 1.4.1):

```
sys.stderr.write(msg)
```

and to find python site packages, you can type this in a terminal (cmd):

```
python -c "import sys; sys.path = sys.path[1:]; import django; print(django.__path__)"
```

Comment: I think you are right. But when I commented the line, the server terminal still printed the 'GET /...' messages. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: that worked on my computer, try restarting the server. Or maybe you are editing the wrong file (multiple django installation), etc.

Comment: Is there any cmd that can hide the messages?

Comment: to hide all output, simply add `>nul 2>&1` to the end of any command. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262708/suppress-command-line-output

Comment: I don't understand, add '>' to where?