# Suppress command line output but still log

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to suppress output (errors mostly) in the command prompt, but still log all other output in a logfile.

Here I found to suppress it in the cmd line output:
[Suppress command line output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262708/suppress-command-line-output)

But how can I do that, while in the mean time all other output will be logged? (to C:\log.txt for example)

Thank you

Comment: `somecommand > outputlog.txt 2>errorlog.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are the two parts `>nul` and `2>&1` in the example provided by you.

`>nul` redirects the output of the script (stdout) to `nul`

`2>&1` redirects the errors (errout) to the default output

If you write `command >nul 2>&1` then errout wil get redirected to stdout and stdout will get redirected to `nul`

If you want to only log the normal output but not the errors use this

```
command >logfile.txt 2>nul
```

Comment: so for example:
`taskkill /im "test.exe" /f >"c:\log.txt" 2>&1` 

?

Comment: Thanks, will try it out and get back to you :)

Comment: just tried this, but the ERROR messages are now in the log - I don't want to include those in the log neither on screen (so no error messages, but others are fine)

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Change 2>&1 to 2>nul

Answer (score 2):

This code can log only the success actions into file ***log.txt***

and all errors are redirected to `nul` :

```
@echo off
set process=Test.exe,test2.exe,calc.exe,skype.exe
For %%a in (%process%) Do Call :KillMyProcess %%a
pause
Exit /b

:KillMyProcess
Taskkill /IM "%~1" /F >> log.txt 2>nul
```