# How to make a "type" command go >nul if "The system cannot find the file specifed"

Tags: batch-file, nul

I have been testing a batch file, that I used to see if my ideas work in batch. I had an idea to make a logging system, but if the file cant be found it doesn't show "*The system cannot find the file specified.*"

I've tried `type A6Test.log &if %ERRORLEVEL%==1 >nul` and `type A6Test.log ^&if %ERRORLEVEL%==1 >nul` but the first just exited the file and the second displayed:

> ```
> The system cannot find the file specified.
> Error occurred while processing: A6Test.log.
> The system cannot find the file specified.
> Error occurred while processing: &If.
> The system cannot find the file specified.
> Error occurred while processing: 1.
> ```

All you need to recreate this is below.

```
@echo off
:A6
cls
echo Log file:
type "A6Test.log" ::Problem
set /p Log=
echo %Log%>>"A6Test.log" ::this echos %log% into the log file, "A6Test.log"
goto A6
```

I expected `type "A6Test.log" ^&if %ERRORLEVEL%==1 >nul` to display nothing if the file didnt exist but it showed:

> ```
> The system cannot find the file specified.
> Error occurred while processing: A6Test.log.
> The system cannot find the file specified.
> Error occurred while processing: &If.
> The system cannot find the file specified.
> Error occurred while processing: 1.
> ```

Comment: `if exist "%filename%" (type "%filename%>>wherever) else (echo "%filename%" is missing)`

Comment: `>nul` redirects *Stdout* to `nul`. `2>nul` redirects *Stderr* to `nul`. Error messages usually are streamed to *Stderr*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Suppress command line output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262708/suppress-command-line-output)

Comment: What is **`%ERRORCODE%`**? Is it related to **`%ERRORLEVEL%`**?

Comment: If **`Type "A6Test.log" 2>NUL`** is what you're wanting to use, you could use that with either **`ErrorLevel`**, **`%ERRORLEVEL%`**; or the **`&&`** and **`||`** operators. Alternatively you could simply use an **`If Exist "A6Test.log"`** statement instead.